# Multi Domain: Is it possible to get all the products in main website(search and product listing)?

Tags: multistore, product-list, catalogsearch, multi-vendor

how to list all the products from all my store websites into the main website in

1. category pages
2. Ajax auto-suggest search

Answer (score 0):

## category pages

Just activate all your products on the main website, then all the products should be listed in the categories (if the index is up to date)

## Ajax auto-suggest search

Should be the same, if the search works, it should show all products available in the store, activate them all and it should work?

Comment: Activate as in ? In the products grid in the admin, select all products with the 'select all' button. From the 'actions' dropdown menu; select 'Update Attributes'. In the 'Websites' tab; select the desired websites and click 'save'. Next, reindex all data: